# Implement vibration in flutter

Tags: flutter, vibration

Is there any to Vibrate the phone even if the Vibration Feedback setting is turned off of the device?

I have tried this piece of code but it will work only when the Vibration Feedback is turned on from the settings.

```
await HapticFeedback.vibrate();
```

I have Even tried [vibration](https://pub.dev/packages/vibration) plugin but won't get success in that as well.

Comment: I do not think this is achievable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, that is not achievable. You can't override the user settings at the phone's system level from an application. That is, if your uses do not want their phone to vibrate, the phone won't vibrate, no matter how you implement it.

If was overridable, it would be a horrible user experience anyways. If I disable the vibrations in my phone's settings it's because I don't want the phone to vibrate in any situation. If all of a sudden an application manages to override that setting to display haptic feedbacks I would be a bit annoyed, and I don't think you want that for your users.

Comment: I think the OP just wants to make his phone vibrate in some way or the other. I have many apps on my phone which can make the phone vibrate despite haptic feedback turned off. The answer should be some other way to do it and not 'HapticFeedback'. However, I dont know the answer, yet. How is it done natively on android? Maybe we can get some cues??

Answer (score 0):

Vibrate for a long time on one click then use following code..

- First of all Add Dependency,

  ```
   dependencies:
   flutter:
      sdk: flutter
               vibration: ^1.7.3     // this is Vibrator Dependency
  ```
- then Go to your main file:
- find the "onTap() {}" event and put the code....

  ```
           Vibration.vibrate(
                pattern: [500, 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000],
              );
  ```